# Remove view from MergeAdapter

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Is it possible to remove view or adapter from `MergeAdapter` somehow? I'd try to extend it and remove the view from `pieces` but it's `private`. Or maybe there's an alternative solution to show/hide view in this adapter? I tried to set its `layout_height` to zero and visibility to `View.GONE`, but it still shows the empty list item. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove a view or an adapter from `MergeAdapter` use the following methods:

`setActive()` on your mergeAdapter Instance.

For Example :
To remove a `Textview` (mytextView) from a `MergeAdapter`(merAdapter) use:

```
merAdapter.setActive(mytextViiew,false);
```

And to enable it again(to make it visible) use:

```
merAdapter.setActive(mytextViiew,true);
```

Refer the `MergeAdapter` documentation for details:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to remove view or adapter from MergeAdapter somehow?

Not presently, sorry. It shouldn't be too hard to add (remove it from the collection and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the `AdapterView`) if you wanted to take a shot at it. Contributions are welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

your MergeAdapter should be having method called `getCount()`.. if i have understood you right, returning zero from there may solve your problem..

Comment: Hi ntc, I assume that returning zero in `getCount()` will hide all views, but I need to hide specific one. For example, I added 2 views, 2 adapters, then again 2 views, and now I wanna remove/hide the 2-nd view.

Comment: well then on getView() method you will get the position of the view requested.. at required position you can set its Visibility as gone.. if you can post bit of your code probably we will be more clear about your purpose,..

Comment: Though setting Visibility of the view onside the `getView()` doesn't hide the list item, I'll try to don't attach the view overriding this method, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ended up with returning the new view with `ListView.LayoutParams` with `width` 0 in `getView()`. I'll accept your answer if the `MergeAdapter`'s author won't reply. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mark Murphy's answer, I think this is as simple as adding this method to MergeAdapter:

```
public void removeAdapter(ListAdapter la) {
    pieces.remove(la);
  }
```

`remove()` takes an object and will do all of the necessary testing & removal for you, if that object is contained in the pieces list.  You could make this return a bool or something for your own purposes, but I had no such need.

Then just call something like:

```
int view_to_remove = *AN_INT*
adapter.removeAdapter(listAdapter.getAdapter(view_to_remove));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If I remember it right, `pieces` has private access in MergeAdapter, so I'd need to modify its sources. I'm not so familiar with GitHub and contributions there so I ended up with some workaround. But thanks for the suggestion.