# How to remove a view from MergeAdapter

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the `MergeAdapter` from [commonsware](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to put several views and one adapter into one list. By the way this is great. But I have problems to remove a particular view from the list. The MergeAdapter doesn't have a method like *removeView(int index)* or *removeView (View v)*.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove view from MergeAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939440/remove-view-from-mergeadapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there is no method like `removeView()` - but what about settings its visibility to `NONE` and then sending `notifyDatSetChanged()` ? I've used this technique in the past to handle UI changes at runtime.

Comment: Ok, that's a start. But when i set the views visibility to GONE, its space will be reserved. So theres a padding at the bottom of the list. Any ideas to handle that?