# MergeAdapter - removing a child adapter + unregisterDataSetObserver()?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'd like to remove an adapter from a MergeAdapter, as per this question:

[Remove view from MergeAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939440/remove-view-from-mergeadapter)

Do we need to clean up the observer registered with the child adapter in addAdapter()? For example:

```
public void addAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    pieces.add(adapter);
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new CascadeDataSetObserver()); /// *** ///
}

public void removeAdapter(int position) {
    ListAdapter adapter = pieces.remove(position);
    adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(????);  //// ??? ////
}
```

Do we need to unregister the datasetobserver here?

Comment: What does the title of your questions have to do with your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You could if you wanted. However, bear in mind that all `registerDataSetObserver()` is doing, in effect, is setting up a reference *from* the added `ListAdapter` *to* the `MergeAdapter`, not the other way around. Hence, so long as you will be discarding your removed `ListAdapter`, the registered observer should also get garbage-collected.